# Exception occurred while getting the javadoc: Unknown javadoc format

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm working on a spigot plugin for Minecraft in Eclipse and the javadoc for spigot suddenly stopped working. If I hover over a spigot method I get the error mentioned in the title. Java internal methods display the javadoc just fine, and so do any methods in my classes that I've added javadoc for. The spigot javadoc location is set to https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/, which is loading fine, and validates just fine.

After doing a little research I found this issue is usually caused by unbound or non-JDK references in Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. I removed all java JDKs and JREs on my system, installed the latest JDK 8u77, and added it in installed JREs. It is the only one listed and it is ticked. The path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77, which is my only JDK installation. I even tried installing the latest version of Eclipse Mars 2 to a different folder, and running clean on my workspace. Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

Using the offline docs worked! Go to [The Maven repository for Spigot](https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/#view-repositories;snapshots~browsestorage~Bukkit).

In the bottom section that says snapshots, click the + next to "org", then "bukkit", then "bukkit" again. Then click the + next to the version of Bukkit you are using. The first file listed should end in "-javadoc.jar". Right-click this file and hit download. Save it to the resources folder of your project. Then edit the javadoc location of the bukkit jar in your build path, and set it to "Javadoc in archive". Browse to the file you just downloaded, select it, and save. Working 100% for me now!

The spigot javadocs are in that same Maven repository, so if you're using spigot just open the spigotmc folder instead of bukkit.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but using IntelliJ should solve the issue. As for why Eclipse can't handle this, I really don't know. It happens to me too, and not only: https://bukkit.org/threads/unknown-javadoc-format-eclipse.414506/ However, other libs seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the link I made a comment there as well. Glad to know I'm not the only one! I'm going to check and see if an offline javadoc is available.